# AppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching is not being called

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

Having troubles with application launching. I've been deleting Main.storyboard from project and trying to create main window from code. At this moment I figured that something went wrong and my AppDelegate is no longer functioning at all.

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        print("OK")
    }
```

The code is straightforward, but it prints nothing, also breakpoint is not triggered at line with print statement. Application building and launching with no problems, but nothing is on screen / in debug output.

Last non-trivial action I've done was erasing *"Main storyboard file base name"* in *Info.plist* file. Could that cause such a problem?

Comment: Unless you are launching your app as a result of a notification, you are using the wrong delegate method.

Comment: The AppDelegate object was in Main.storyboard which is deleted.

Comment: @picciano no, this is the correct `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method.

Comment: @Willeke so NSApplicationMain annotation does nothing itself?

Comment: Good point, is `AppDelegate` instantiated?